# OpenNetCF.Net.NetworkInformation.Adapter class is missing

Tags: compact-framework, opennetcf

I have donwloaded OpenNETCF's Smart Device Framework but both

`OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation.Adapter`

AND

`OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation.AdapterCollection`

yield a

"namespace is missing or not available" error from the compiler.

I am using OpenNetCF.Net  Version 2.3.1.12004.0

Answer (score 0):

Those are from the old 1.4 version, before I cleaned out a load of redundancy.  What you want is this:

```
var adapters = OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adaptor and AdaptorCollection class are the older version of Opennetcf.net.

The newer version contains AccessPoint and AccessPointCollection.

However, you can get the addaptor by using like this,

```
INetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
```

from `using OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation;` Then, you can typecase nics depending on the type of network interfaces, like wirelessNetworkInterface, wirelessZeroConfiguredNetworkInterface etc.